# Conjugacy problem for matrices (finding the conjugator)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given matrices $A$ and $B$, I've learned ways to show that $A$ and $B$ are conjugate, for example, two matrices are similar if and only if they have the same Jordan normal form.

However, are there algorithms to compute the conjugator, i.e. the matrix $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP?$ The equation $PB = AP$ gives us $n^2$ linear equations, but would a solution of those equations always give an invertible matrix?

I'm assuming the answer would be different depending on which matrix ring you're working in, so in my case, I'm specifically asking about the matrix ring $M_n(\mathbb{Z}[t^{\pm 1}])$ over the Laurent polynomials (with integer coefficients).

Comment: The Jordan normal form algorithm (or the Frobenius normal form algorithm, if you are over a non-algebraically closed field) gives you not just the Jordan blocks, but also the conjugator between your matrix and the Jordan-block matrix. Be careful with $\mathbb{Z}\left[t^{\pm 1}\right]$, though; this is not a field, and the standard theory of Jordan normal forms does not apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with matrices with entries in an algebraically closed field, then Jordan form is perfect.  Once we know the common Jordan form $J$, we find conjugators $P_1,P_2$ such that
$$
J = P_1^{-1}AP_1\\
J = P_2^{-1}BP_2
$$
It follows that
$$
B = P_2JP_2^{-1} = P_2(P_1^{-1}AP_1)P_2^{-1} = (P_1P_2^{-1})^{-1}A(P_1P_2^{-1})
$$
Unfortunately, Jordan form fails in its role as a canonical form when your matrix entries are not taken from a field.  The next best thing would be [the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain), which again allows us to select a canonical representative of an equivalence class.  This also fails to do the job, however, since $\mathbb Z[t^{\pm 1}]$ is not a principal ideal domain.

What you *can* do, however, is take these matrices to have entries in $\mathbb{Q}[t^{\pm 1}]$, which is a PID containing $\mathbb Z[t^{\pm 1}]$.  You might get lucky and find that the canonical form and conjugators use only integer coefficients.